# how to get appbar in windows 8 metro applications using visual studio 2012?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

I am developing a metro application using visual studio 2012. I am trying to get an AppBar in my metro application. How do I do that?

Comment: Your question is unnecessarily hard to read. Please improve its wording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a LOT of samples in the MSDN Dev Center, http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsapps. One of them is specifically an [AppBar sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-AppBar-control-sample-2aa1cbb4), and the description reads:

> This sample demonstrates how to use the AppBar control to present
>   navigation, commands, and tools to users.
>
> The app bar is hidden by default and appears when users swipe a finger
>   from the top or bottom edge of the screen. It covers the content of
>   the app and can be dismissed by the user with an edge swipe, or by
>   interacting with the app. This sample shows how to add an app bar,
>   customize the app bar, and control the app bar. Also, it shows how to
>   use sticky app bars and global app bars.

I think this will get you started.

Comment: Kate,Thank u so much.and as the same way i need to work on HeaderMenu in metro-apps.can u please have a look at my other question once(Windows8 metro: HeaderMenu).